# Does Eclipse have an option for personal version control of local workspaces?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin, rcs

Does Eclipse have an option for personal version control of local workspaces?  Like a version control plugin that I can get through the auto-update that doesn't require installation anything additional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe eGit should do what you want.  Among other things Git does local version control for projects managed with other version control systems.